# Mean absorption time, two absorbing states

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I have a transition matrix
$$ P = \begin{Vmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 &0\\
.3& 0 &.7& 0\\
0& .1 & 0 & .9 \\
0& 0 & 0 &1
\end{Vmatrix}$$
on states $\{0,1,2,3\}$. I'm trying to calculate the mean time until absorption starting at state 1.
I set up a system of equations and got $v_0 = v_3 = 0$, and
\begin{align*}
v_1 &= .7v_2+1\\
v_2&= .1v_1+1.
\end{align*}
Solving for $v_1$ gives $\frac{170}{93}$.

Then I'm asked to use results regarding random walks to solve this, but I don't have any.

My questions are:

1. Is my system of equations correct?
2. What results can I use about random walks to solve this?
   Thanks!

Comment: Typo in matrix, sorry.

Comment: Your calculation is correct.  If you are taking a course, you might ask your instructor what results regarding random walks the problem is referring to, or consult your textbook, if you have one.

Comment: Ok thanks! I just wasn't sure what to do when there are **two** absorbing states. I understand this is how it works for one absorbing state. I guess then that it is true that the boundary condition is $v_i = 0$ for each $i$ that is an absorbing state?

Comment: Sure.  If you are in an absorbing state, no steps are needed to get into an absorbing state, so the expected number of steps is zero.